# Given a date I want to to return a date that is one month prior that falls on the first business day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given

```
DECLARE @ArchiveDate date = '5/1/2019';
```

I want `'4/1/2019'` to be returned.

Another example is given @ArchiveDate date = '7/1/2019';`then`'6/3/2019'` Will be returned.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't natively know what "business days" are. It can find the Monday following a weekend easily enough, but it doesn't know about location specific holidays, corporate holidays, etc. You really need to build a business specific calendar table for this, which is enormously well documented across the internet. And once you have that built, this issue becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(day, 
        CASE WHEN 
            DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @ArchiveDate)) = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @ArchiveDate)) = 7 THEN 2
        ELSE 0
        END
    , DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @ArchiveDate))
```

What this does is it first subtracts a month from @ArchiveDate, then adds an offset if it lands on Saturday or Sunday (using DATEPART). Note that this won't account for any holidays. As far as I know, there's no built in list of holidays, so you'll need a more complex system if that is needed - perhaps a user defined function that returns the offset needed for a given day.

Comment: Please note that this might return incorrect data depending on the setting of DATEFIRST. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017